# How to make a CSS transform run from its current position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m making a game using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. When I click the left arrow, the red and yellow box jerks to the original position and runs. I want it to run at the position it is at currently at. Same goes for double tapping the arrows.
I’ve attached a Repl.it. Here it is: https://repl.it/@ritzcrackerz201/cake

Comment: Why are you not using a game engine like babylon.js ?

Comment: @Marc I just want to make a game using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: ...babylon.js is written in JavaScript...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I just don’t want to use a game engine. I’m honing my JavaScript skill.

Comment: Fair enough. In any case, Stack Overflow requires code to be on this site, not on an external site. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide a runnable example here.

Comment: Please edit this question so the code is in the question itself. If you then ping me at `@halfer` I can help you get the question reopened. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below I have edited your script, Your main issue was you were using two different values for your left and right movement... Also i don't know if this is what you wanted but I made edits to your 'jump' section of code.

**Javascript**

```
<script>
  let xArrowMovement = 0;
  let jumpboxupmovementy = 0;
  // let player = null;
  // let playerPos = null;

  /*setTimeout(function(){ 
    getElements();
  }, 100);

  function getElements() {
    console.log('Entered getElements');

    player = document.getElementById("master-cube");
    console.log(player);
    playerPos = player.style.transform;
    console.log(playerPos);
  } */

  function moveright() {
    console.log('Entered moveright');

    xArrowMovement += 80;
    document.getElementById("master-cube").style.transform = `translate(${xArrowMovement}%, ${jumpboxupmovementy}%)`;

  }

  function moveleft() {
    console.log('Entered moveleft');

   xArrowMovement -= 80;
   document.getElementById("master-cube").style.transform = `translate(${xArrowMovement}%, ${jumpboxupmovementy}%)`;

  }

  function movejump() {
    console.log('Entered movejump: ' + xArrowMovement + ' ' + jumpboxupmovementy);

    jumpboxupmovementy += 80;
    document.getElementById("master-cube").style.transform = `translate(${xArrowMovement}%, ${-jumpboxupmovementy}%)`;
    //wait for this animation to complete

    setTimeout(function(){ 
      jumpboxupmovementy -= 80;
      document.getElementById("master-cube").style.transform = `translate(${xArrowMovement}%, ${jumpboxupmovementy}%)`;
    }, 500); 

  }

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="master-cube"></div>
 <img src="arrows/leftarrow.png" alt="Left Arrow" height="80vh" width="80vw" onclick="moveleft()" class="arrowcontrols">
 <img src="arrows/middlejumpsquare.png" alt="Jump Square" height="80vh" width="80vw" onclick="movejump()" class="arrowcontrols">
 <img src="arrows/rightarrow.png" alt="Right Arrow" height="80vh" width="80vw" onclick="moveright()" class="arrowcontrols">
</body>
```

Comment: Hey, you typed "were using to different" it sounds like you meant to type "two" not "to".

Comment: If you press the right arrow a couple of times and then the jump box, it skips back to the original position. This is what I don’t want to happen.

Comment: @JeffreyLan I have made several edits to my answer, One thing i tried but couldn't get to work (which i think would be very valuable in the long run) was to get your 'player' object and it position as variables, Another thing to point out is the `console.log` calls I find these extremely helpful while debugging and would recommend you doing the same :)

Comment: @DylanAnlezark Now there’s a new problem. When I press the right arrow a couple of times and then I press the left arrow once, it executes the right arrow, when it’s supposed to execute the left arrow function. What’s the reason behind this? What should I do to fix it?

Comment: @JeffreyLan I can't seem to replicate that issue.
What browser (Chrome, IE, Edge) and operating system (Windows, Mac) are you using that might have something to do with it?

Comment: @DylanAnlezark I'm using Safari and Google Chrome. My operating system is the latest for iPadOS.

Comment: @JeffreyLan Unfortunately I was still unable to recreate this issue, I would now create a new stack overflow question targeting this issue exactly with any new edits to your code you may of made since asking this question, Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks. I'll let this be the answer. I'll ask a new question. Thank you for your hard work!

Answer (score 0):

Use `translate( 0, 0 )` instead of `translateX( 0 )`, `translateY( 0 )`. And use one value of x instead of `leftarrowmovement` and `rightarrowmovelock`. Now after clicking left function doesn't consider your movement to the right.

But as stated in @Marc's comment, you should use some kind of engine for that. CSS is not the best tool in development of such games.

Comment: Is it necessary to use translate(0,0) instead of translateY()?

Comment: @JeffreyLan now when you apply `translateY`, you remove `translateX` so the box returns to the point 0.

Comment: You can use `translateX(100%) translateY(150%)` instead of `translate(100%, 150%)` but the effect will the same.